# I can't seem to fix the error with gunicorn, the logs is as shown below

Tags: heroku

```
2018-09-29T15:33:25.160299+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-09-29T15:33:25.141050+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2018-09-29T15:33:25.048441+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.stop()
2018-09-29T15:33:25.048444+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2018-09-29T15:33:25.048656+00:00 app[web.1]:     time.sleep(0.1)
2018-09-29T15:33:25.048693+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld
2018-09-29T15:33:25.048898+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.reap_workers()
2018-09-29T15:33:25.048910+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2018-09-29T15:33:25.049163+00:00 app[web.1]:     raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2018-09-29T15:33:25.049169+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>`
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's going to be very difficult to answer this question without a lot more detail. Please read [ask]. For starters, the code you're trying to run would be helpful. More context in the error message might help too. You can [edit] your question and add details to it.

Answer (score 0):

Because of few details, we only knew it seems related to gunicorn.errors.HaltServer error.

You may refer to [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=gunicorn.errors.HaltServer) and report what you found. Good luck!